# How to change x values on scatter plot

Tags: r

I have a project I am working on and the X values on my scatter plot go from 0-1400. I would like the upper X value to be 80, but I cannot find a way to do this.

My code is:

```
plot(Toyota.df$Price - Toyota.df$Age_08_04, xlab = "Age", ylab = "Price")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Plecos, try this:

```
 plot(Toyota.df$Price - Toyota.df$Age_08_04, xlab = "Age", ylab = "Price", xlim=c(0,80))
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Can you mark my solution as the answer?  Thanks!